# Designing A Simplified MIPS Processor

Tags: mips

So I'm going over some old quizzes for my Computer Organization final and I must have missed this lecture or something. I'm decently proficient in programming MIPS, but this problem has me completely stumped. Could someone help me understand this?

[image]

Comment: Your figure looks a lot like your prof probably started with an [easily available diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MIPS_Architecture_(Pipelined).svg) and removed that parts he didn't care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram is missing lines connecting the various parts of the processor as well as a multiplexor for determining if the next instruction address is coming from the PC+4 or from a register as in a `jr ra` instruction.

There needs to be a line from the ALU to the write data portion of the register file. This is for R-Type instructions, as their result will need to be written back to the destination register. Going into the ALU needs to be lines from Read data 1 and Read data 2, this is how the values from the registers make their way into the ALU for R-type instructions.

A couple lines have been added from the instruction memory to the registers, you're missing the one to the Write Register though (this specifies the destination register for R-type instructions).

For the PC, the line going *into* the adder goes into the other input (the above one). The 4 for the adder is constant, as each instruction address is 4 bytes after the previous one, so unless we're jumping to an address we will be executing the instruction immediately after the current instruction. The line from the PC to the read address is also necessary as the PC specifies which instruction address to find the current instruction at. The line going into the PC comes from either the result of the PC+4 addition *or* from the register specified in a `jr ra` instruction.

To handle this decision a multiplexor is needed. Multiplexors have two inputs and one output, so this one will have one input from the PC+4 adder (for regular R-type instructions) and another from Read Data 1 (for `jr ra` instructions). The input from Read Data 1 should be visualized as a split from the line between Read Data 1 and the ALU. The output will go right back to the PC, as it determines the next instruction to execute.

I think that's everything that's wanted for that question, as the prof specifies that control signals are already generated (the multiplexor is a type of control unit, but I think it's necessary nonetheless). Hope that helps!